# How to run executables from terminal in Linux without entering the entire PATH

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I'm trying to activate android studio directly from terminal (./studio.sh)
the installation dir is /usr/local/android-studio
and inside there's a bin folder with the script studio.sh

for that I've vi'd ~/.bashrc to include the following line:
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/android-studio/bin

When I do echo $PATH i do see the path above appended to the rest of the path
(/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/android-studio/bin)

**Yet when I run ./studio.sh it prompts me with No such file or directory**

Needless to say, if i cd /usr/local/android-studio/bin and then ./studio.sh it works fine

running debian (jessie 'edition')

Comment: have you tried just typing studio.sh (without the ./studio.sh)?

Comment: @PS I haven't beforehand, I just did a sudo chmod +x studio.sh when I was within the directory.. still no go

Comment: @ZanCoul yup, that did it, I feel stupid now. :) thanks a lot!

Comment: Just run studio.sh in your terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply needed to do studio.sh without the ./ 
Thanks for ZanCoul for providing the answer.

Comment: Just to be clear, the `.` is another name for the current directory.  Every directory has (at least) two names, the one we usually use and `.`.  It is not an alias or a short-cut, but a proper name held in the directory itself.